# How to create a function with variable amount of parameters in order to generate SQL request (python)?

Tags: python, sql, parameters, wildcard

I would like to create a "generic" function that contains SQL SELECT, but I want this function to be able to accept some parameters that are not defined.

I have this code:

```
def request(self, identifier= "%", sender="%", receiver="%", context="%", state="%"):
    result = None
    myConnection = MemoryManagement().getConnection()
    myCursor = myConnection.cursor()
    myCursor.execute("SELECT * from MemorySpace WHERE id = ? and sender = ? and receiver = ? and context = ? and state = ?", (identifier, sender, receiver, context, state))
    result = myCursor.fetchall()
    myCursor.close()
    myConnection.close()
    return result
```

The thing is that the "%" does not work as a wildcard...I would like to know if there is a solution that I could program myself for this problem ? (i.e. I do not want to use a framework or any kind of layer to access the sql database :) )

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Use `**kwargs` so you get can named arguments that don't have to be given per se. Use `*args` if you don't know any of your arguments (yet).

Comment: % works as a wildcard if you use the keyword like and the field is text.  Your id field might not be.  However, it sounds like you want to retrieve some records without knowing which ones.  The technical term for that is, "bad idea".

Comment: The `bad idea` terminology can only be found on the MSDN, don't worry :P

Comment: @DanBracuk the "id" does not matter, you can remove it from the code example. It's not that I do not know which record I want, the thing is that I do not know the exact request that will be executed : that's why I am trying to make a ---generic--- function !

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this :)

Also adds some reusability

```
BASE_QUERY = '''
SELECT *
FROM MemorySpace
'''

def get_connection(self):
    return MemoryManagement().getConnection()

def get_result(self, query, args):
    cursor = self.get_connection()
    cursor.execute(query, args)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return result

def request(self, **kwargs):
    args = []
    filters = []

    for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
        filters.append('%s = ?' % k)
        args.append(v)

    query = BASE_QUERY
    if filters:
        query += ' AND '.join(filters)

    return self.get_result(query, args)
```